# Find time to nearest occurrence of particular value for each row

Tags: r, time, data.table

Say I have a data table:

```
dt <- data.table(
        datetime = seq(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 00:00:00"),as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 10:00:00"), by = "1 hour"),
        ObType = c("A","A","B","B","B","B","A","A","B","A","A")
)

dt
                   datetime ObType
     1: 2016-01-01 00:00:00      A
     2: 2016-01-01 01:00:00      A
     3: 2016-01-01 02:00:00      B
     4: 2016-01-01 03:00:00      B
     5: 2016-01-01 04:00:00      B
     6: 2016-01-01 05:00:00      B
     7: 2016-01-01 06:00:00      A
     8: 2016-01-01 07:00:00      A
     9: 2016-01-01 08:00:00      B
    10: 2016-01-01 09:00:00      A
    11: 2016-01-01 10:00:00      A
```

What I need to do is wherever the ObType is "B", I need to find the time to the nearest ObType "A" on either side. So the result should look like (in hours):

```
               datetime ObType timeLag timeLead
 1: 2016-01-01 00:00:00      A      NA       NA
 2: 2016-01-01 01:00:00      A      NA       NA
 3: 2016-01-01 02:00:00      B       1        4
 4: 2016-01-01 03:00:00      B       2        3
 5: 2016-01-01 04:00:00      B       3        2
 6: 2016-01-01 05:00:00      B       4        1
 7: 2016-01-01 06:00:00      A      NA       NA
 8: 2016-01-01 07:00:00      A      NA       NA
 9: 2016-01-01 08:00:00      B       1        1
10: 2016-01-01 09:00:00      A      NA       NA
11: 2016-01-01 10:00:00      A      NA       NA
```

I usually use data.table, but non data.table solutions are also fine.

Thanks!

Lyss

Comment: Sorry I don't have time for full answer,  but `roll="nearest"` likely needed.  Perhaps something like `lookup = setkey(DT[ObType=="A"], datetime)`  and then join just the B's to `lookup` using `roll="nearest"`.  More info on the bigger picture would be useful please in case it can be done a different way.

Comment: Are there only these two "ObTypes"? You could, simply, try `findInterval` -- `a = dt$datetime[dt$ObType == "A"]; ib = dt$ObType == "B"; b = dt$datetime[ib]; i = findInterval(b, a); cbind(replace(NA, ib, b - a[i]), replace(NA, ib, a[i + 1] - b))`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The approach I hinted at using `roll=` :

```
X = dt[ObType=="A"]
X
              datetime ObType
1: 2016-01-01 00:00:00      A
2: 2016-01-01 01:00:00      A
3: 2016-01-01 06:00:00      A
4: 2016-01-01 07:00:00      A
5: 2016-01-01 09:00:00      A
6: 2016-01-01 10:00:00      A

dt[ObType=="B", Lag:=X[.SD,on="datetime",roll=Inf,i.datetime-x.datetime]]
dt[ObType=="B", Lead:=X[.SD,on="datetime",roll=-Inf,x.datetime-i.datetime]]
dt[ObType=="B", Nearest:=X[.SD,on="datetime",roll="nearest",x.datetime-i.datetime]]
dt
               datetime ObType      Lag     Lead     Nearest
 1: 2016-01-01 00:00:00      A NA hours NA hours    NA hours
 2: 2016-01-01 01:00:00      A NA hours NA hours    NA hours
 3: 2016-01-01 02:00:00      B  1 hours  4 hours    -1 hours
 4: 2016-01-01 03:00:00      B  2 hours  3 hours    -2 hours
 5: 2016-01-01 04:00:00      B  3 hours  2 hours     2 hours
 6: 2016-01-01 05:00:00      B  4 hours  1 hours     1 hours
 7: 2016-01-01 06:00:00      A NA hours NA hours    NA hours
 8: 2016-01-01 07:00:00      A NA hours NA hours    NA hours
 9: 2016-01-01 08:00:00      B  1 hours  1 hours    -1 hours
10: 2016-01-01 09:00:00      A NA hours NA hours    NA hours
11: 2016-01-01 10:00:00      A NA hours NA hours    NA hours
```

One advantage of `roll=` is that you can apply a staleness limit just by changing the `Inf` to the limit of time you wish to join within. It's the time difference that the limit applies to, not the number of rows. `Inf` just means don't limit. The `roll=` sign indicates whether to look forwards or backwards (lead or lag).

Another advantage is that `roll=` is fast.

Comment: why not `setkey(dt, ObType, datetime)` first, and then use `dt["B", Lag:=...`?

Comment: @setempler Yes that `setkey()` would work too and would be faster but I got the impression the OP didn't want to change the order of their data: it's ordered by time and has A's then B's then A's then B's.

Answer (score 3):

```
dt$timelag = NA
dt$timelead = NA

A = split(dt, dt$ObType)$A
B = split(dt, dt$ObType)$B

A_time_up = sort(A$datetime)
A_time_dn = sort(A$datetime, decreasing = TRUE)

B$timelag = apply(B, 1, function(x) 
    A_time_up[which(x[1] < A_time_up)[1]]
)

B$timelead = apply(B, 1, function(x) 
    A_time_dn[which(x[1] > A_time_dn)[1]]
)

B$timelag = (B$timelag - as.numeric(B$datetime))/(3600)
B$timelead = (as.numeric(B$datetime) - B$timelead)/(3600)

rbind(A,B)
```

Comment: `sort(A$datetime)` is a full sort of all of `A$datetime` repeated 4 times for each and  every row.  If this works, it'll be very slow, iiuc.

Comment: @MattDowle, I've taken care of sorting multiple times (I think)

Comment: Yep looks better now.

Comment: Thanks d.b.. this is a good solution too, however the one above is faster and since I have over 100 million rows this is important :)

Answer (score 3):

Two approaches, one using joins, the other using reshaping

### Joins

There is probably a better approach that uses rolling joins / non-equi joins, but here's a brute-force approach

```
dt2 <- dt[, key := 1][ 
    dt, 
    on = "key", 
    allow.cartesian = T
    ][
        ObType != i.ObType
        ][
            , `:=`(lag_min = datetime - i.datetime,
                         lag_max = i.datetime - datetime)
            ]


dt_min <- dt2[ObType == "B" & lag_min > 0, .(timeLag = min(lag_min)), by = .(datetime, ObType)]
dt_max <- dt2[ObType == "B" & lag_max > 0, .(timeLead = min(lag_max)), by = .(datetime, ObType)]


dt_max[ dt_min[ dt, on = c("datetime", "ObType"), nomatch = NA], on = c("datetime", "ObType"), nomatch = NA]

#                datetime ObType  lag_max  lag_min key
#  1: 2016-01-01 00:00:00      A NA hours NA hours   1
#  2: 2016-01-01 01:00:00      A NA hours NA hours   1
#  3: 2016-01-01 02:00:00      B  4 hours  1 hours   1
#  4: 2016-01-01 03:00:00      B  3 hours  2 hours   1
#  5: 2016-01-01 04:00:00      B  2 hours  3 hours   1
#  6: 2016-01-01 05:00:00      B  1 hours  4 hours   1
#  7: 2016-01-01 06:00:00      A NA hours NA hours   1
#  8: 2016-01-01 07:00:00      A NA hours NA hours   1
#  9: 2016-01-01 08:00:00      B  1 hours  1 hours   1
# 10: 2016-01-01 09:00:00      A NA hours NA hours   1
# 11: 2016-01-01 10:00:00      A NA hours NA hours   1
```

### Reshaping

It's quite involved, and some of the steps can obviously be simplified, but I'm throwing it all in here anyway so you can see the process

```
dt[, group := rleid(ObType)]
dt_cast <- dcast(dt, formula = datetime + group ~ ObType, value.var = "ObType")

dt_cast[, `:=`(group_before = group - 1,
                             group_after = group + 1)]


dt_min <- dt_cast[ !is.na(B) ][dt_cast[!is.na(A), .(datetime, group)] , on = c(group_before = "group")  , allow.cartesian = T][, max(i.datetime), by = group]
dt_max <- dt_cast[ !is.na(B) ][dt_cast[!is.na(A), .(datetime, group)] , on = c(group_after = "group")  , allow.cartesian = T][, min(i.datetime), by = group]


dt_cast <- rbindlist(list(
    dt_cast[ dt_min, on = c("group"), nomatch = 0],
    dt_cast[ dt_max, on = c("group"), nomatch = 0]
))

dt <- dt_cast[ dt, on = c("datetime", "group"), nomatch = NA][, .(datetime, ObType, lag = V1)]

dt[ObType == "B" , lag_type := c("lag", "lead"), by = .(datetime, ObType)]
dt <- dcast(dt, formula = datetime + ObType ~ lag_type, value.var = "lag")

dt[, `:=`(timeLag = difftime(datetime, lag),
                    timeLead = difftime(lead, datetime),
                    `NA` = NULL)]

dt
#                datetime ObType                 lag                lead  timeLag timeLead
#  1: 2016-01-01 00:00:00      A                <NA>                <NA> NA hours NA hours
#  2: 2016-01-01 01:00:00      A                <NA>                <NA> NA hours NA hours
#  3: 2016-01-01 02:00:00      B 2016-01-01 01:00:00 2016-01-01 06:00:00  1 hours  4 hours
#  4: 2016-01-01 03:00:00      B 2016-01-01 01:00:00 2016-01-01 06:00:00  2 hours  3 hours
#  5: 2016-01-01 04:00:00      B 2016-01-01 01:00:00 2016-01-01 06:00:00  3 hours  2 hours
#  6: 2016-01-01 05:00:00      B 2016-01-01 01:00:00 2016-01-01 06:00:00  4 hours  1 hours
#  7: 2016-01-01 06:00:00      A                <NA>                <NA> NA hours NA hours
#  8: 2016-01-01 07:00:00      A                <NA>                <NA> NA hours NA hours
#  9: 2016-01-01 08:00:00      B 2016-01-01 07:00:00 2016-01-01 09:00:00  1 hours  1 hours
# 10: 2016-01-01 09:00:00      A                <NA>                <NA> NA hours NA hours
# 11: 2016-01-01 10:00:00      A                <NA>                <NA> NA hours NA hours
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the solution with joins. I have a set of ID's i need to repeat this with, so I'm combining it with ddply... Would it be possible if there was an ID column to also just join on 'ID' as well as 'key' ?

Comment: @LyssBucks - of course. You might be able to replace `key` with your `ID`. I just created `key` so it all joined together.

Comment: Perfect! Works like a dream :)